# Google Apps Script Pasting Blank Cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently trying to copy the data from one sheet and pasting it into the first blank range of cells on another sheet. The script debugs ok, and seems to run ok, but when I look at the second sheet, the destination range is blank. I'm scratching my head in sheer wonder. Any help would be appreciated.

`Google Apps Script`

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("SnapshotSpreadsheet!A2:L2");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Monthly Balance Sheet");
  for (i=2; i<31; i++) {
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1,i);
    var result = destRange.isBlank();
    if (result == "true"){
    source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
        }
  }
```

Comment: Oh, and the data being used is a string (mixed alphanumeric)

Comment: `isBlank()` returns the boolean. But in your script, the boolean value is compared with the string. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank()) By this, the if statement doesn't work. In order to avoid this issue, if your script is modified, how about modifying from `if (result == "true"){` to `if (result === true){` or `if (result){`?

Comment: if (result){ worked perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`if (result){` worked as intended

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24199001)

Comment: @Andreas It does provide an answer to the question, and furthermore the asker is answering his own question.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.